# Python Flask after_request and before_request for a specific set of request

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

A function defined with tags `after_request(f)` and `before_request(f)` runs before and after *every* request. Is it possible to define functions that are run for only specific sets of requests?

For example, I want a function to execute only when requests to accessing resources in static directory are made. Or, maybe I want to differentiate between different types of requests. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: can use blueprints to separate routes out, then perhaps a custom decorator  can be applied to all routes in the blueprint?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is with wrappers.

```
def wrapper_name(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Execute before function
        rv = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # Execute after function
        return rv
    wrapper.__name__ = func.__name__
    return wrapper

@app.route('/foo')
@wrapper_name
def foo():
    return "This gets passed to rv"
```